# Getting unique rows from pairs of rows that only differ in one value (observation)

Tags: r, data.table, unique

I have a data.table that have many pairs of rows that differs in the value of q.val.  For each of these pairs I want to select the row that have the smaller value. In others words I want to go from DT1 to DT2 (see below). Is there a easy way to do this in `data.table` package or other?

```
DT1
cluster q.val
c1  8.68E-03
c1  1.00E+00
c2  4.53E-05
c2  1.00E+00
c3  2.46E-03
c3  1.00E+00
c4  4.18E-05
c4  1.00E+00
c5  1.00E+00
c5  3.98E-05
c6  1.00E+00
c6  4.71E-06

DT2
cluster q.val
c1  8.68E-03
c2  4.53E-05
c3  2.46E-03
c4  4.18E-05
c5  3.98E-05
c6  4.71E-06
```

Given the answers I have edited by original question to post a part of my real table

```
cluster pathway q.val
c1  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -3.01E-06
c1  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -1.80E+00
c2  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -5.07E-06
c2  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -1.30E+00
c3  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -1.46E-06
c3  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -2.32E+00
c4  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -1.60E-05
c4  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -1.75E+00
c5  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  2.58E+00
c5  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  2.53E-06
c6  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  3.54E+00
c6  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  8.74E-08
c7  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -4.85E-02
c7  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  -3.98E-03
c8  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  9.73E-01
c8  Adrenergic signaling in cardiomyocytes  3.44E-05
c1  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -3.01E-06
c1  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.64E+00
c2  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -5.07E-06
c2  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.49E+00
c3  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.46E-06
c3  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.85E+00
c4  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.60E-05
c4  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.40E+00
c5  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion 2.58E+00
c5  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion 2.53E-06
c6  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion 3.45E+00
c6  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion 8.74E-08
c7  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.28E-02
c7  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion -1.42E-02
c8  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion 4.24E-01
c8  Aldosterone synthesis and secretion 3.44E-05
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DT1[, min(q.val), by = c("cluster", "pathway")]
```

The basic syntax in data.table allows you to use the "by" statement to discriminate where a function (in this case 'min') is applied. Worth noting that this will only work if there are not multiple distinct pathways per cluster. If there are, there will be multiple rows for each cluster.

Comment: OP wants to select the row. If there are other columns, this will lose them. Could do `DT1[, .SD[which.min(q.val)], by=cluster]` for that

Comment: ^^ This is true, though I assumed there were no other columns due to the example data set.

Comment: Yes, I oversimplified my example, I have edited my original question now with a subset of my real data.table